# Vuetify - v-data-table break the height of a v-card

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify for development a dashboard. I need all cards whit a specific height, in this case 450px. I fill the v-data-table from axios petition, when the v-data-table fill whit data, it break the height of v-card.

See the v-card **Tabla Tarificador carteras**

[image]

this is my v-card component code:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" md="7">
        <v-card height="450">
            <v-card-text>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-data-table
                            :fixed-header="true"
                            :headers="tablas.tarificadorCarteras.cabeceras"
                            :items="tablas.tarificadorCarteras.datos"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:[`item.cartera`]="{ item }">
                                <a @click="obtenerGraficoTarificadorCartera(item.cartera)" class="text-capitalize">{{ item.cartera }}</a> 
                            </template>
                            <template v-slot:[`item.minutos_entel`]="{ item }">
                                {{ new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL').format(item.minutos_entel) }}
                            </template>
                            <template v-slot:[`item.minutos_movistar`]="{ item }">
                                {{ new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL').format(item.minutos_movistar) }}
                            </template>
                            <template v-slot:[`item.minutos_pacifico`]="{ item }">
                                {{ new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL').format(item.minutos_pacifico) }}
                            </template>
                        </v-data-table>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I need see the v-data-table inside the v-card scrollable and responsive. I try to make it, but can't

Answer (score 0):

Set `max-height="450" style="overflow-y:auto"` to `v-col`

Comment: I set the options, but the v-data-table still break the v-card height https://ibb.co/KK4GV3k

Comment: Did you remove `height="450"` from v-card?

Comment: So try bare css: `style="overflow-y:auto;max-height:450px"` on one from the tags up to v-data-table. This should solve your issue